# ¿Cómo comparar columnas completas en Excel VBA usando WorkSheetFunction?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente problema.

La función `Max.Si.Conjunto` no se encuentra disponible en Excel 2010, por lo que para llegar al mismo objetivo se usa algo como:

```
=MAX(SI(Y(F:F="llave1";P:P=10);L:L))
```

¿Cómo puedo escribir eso como una `WorkSheetFunction`?

He pensado en algo como:

```
 sesionesMes = WorksheetFunction.Max( _
                            WorksheetFunction.IF( _
                                    WorksheetFunction.And(Columns(7) = llave, Columns(16) = mes), _
                                    Columns(12) _
                            ) _
                        )
```

Como equivalente de esto:

```
sesionesMes = WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(Columns(12), Columns(7), llave, Columns(16), mes)
```

Pero definitivamente no funciona, no sé cómo llevar a cabo la comparación de la columna completa cuando se trabaja con `WorkSheetFunction`.

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score -1):

Ahí tienes, intenté tu problema y recibí ayuda de nuestros amigos de Stackoverflow

```
Function MaxIf(RangoUno As Range, RUno As Variant, RangoDos As Range, RDos As Variant, RangoTres As Range) As Variant
Dim x() As Variant, y() As Variant, z() As Variant, w() As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ConstraintUno As Variant, ConstraintDos As Variant, k As Long
i = 1
k = 0
ConstraintUno = RUno 'Restricción 1
ConstraintDos = RDos  ' Restricción 2
 x = RangoUno 'Rango que contiene la primera restricción
 y = RangoDos  'Rango que contiene la segunda restricción
 z = RangoTres 'Rango que contiene los valores numéricos
  For i = 1 To RangoUno.Rows.Count
   If x(i, 1) = RUno Then
    If y(i, 1) = RDos Then
    k = k + 1
    ReDim Preserve w(k)
     w(k) = z(i, 1) ' w() es una matriz que almacena los valores numéricos en cuya fila cumpla con las restricciones 1 y 2
      End If
    End If
   Next i
MaxIf = Application.Max(w)
End Function
'El código tiene área de mejora al incluir de manera dinámica el numero de condiciones como hace la función definida en Excel 2016 max.siconjunto
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006634/user-difined-function-to-emulate-max-ifs-in-vba-2010?noredirect=1#comment69223146_41006634